# How do I add Group support to a mocked Client in a SignalR 2.x unit testing framework?

Tags: c#, signalr, moq, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm using Moq to build up a UnitTest framework for my SignalR 2.x application.
I am currently mocking up my Clients by:

```
var mockClients = new Mock<IHubCallerConnectionContext>();
Clients = mockClients.Object;
```

In order to test, I need to test sending messages by Group:

```
Clients.Group(groupName).sendSomeMessage(message);
```

How do I add Group support to my mocked up Client?

Answer (score 2):

Check this:
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/release/tests/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Tests/Server/Hubs/HubFacts.cs

```
 public void HubsGroupAreMockable()
        {
            var hub = new MyTestableHub();
            var mockClients = new Mock<IHubCallerConnectionContext<dynamic>>();
            var groups = new Mock<IClientContract>();

            hub.Clients = mockClients.Object;
            groups.Setup(m => m.send(It.IsAny<string>())).Verifiable();
            mockClients.Setup(m => m.Group("test")).Returns(groups.Object);
            hub.SendGroup("test", "foo");

            groups.VerifyAll();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/troubleshooting-and-debugging/unit-testing-signalr-applications) tutorial by the SingalR team.

Comment: This is the sample that I originally started with. It's really customized to the sample signalr chat application. It's a good start, but it doesn't go into the detail I need. The messages are broadcast to "ALL" clients. I need to mock the group object so I can broadcast to members of specific groups as part of my unit tests. (Please refer to sample code above). Can anyone help point me in the direction of how to mock a Group object? JB

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that a certain group was notified you should be able to do something like this (this is SignalR 2):

```
public interface IClientContract
{
    void RaiseAlert(string message);
}

[Test]
public void NotifiesOnlySpecifiedGroupWhenGroupIdSent()
{
    // Adapted from code here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/dev/tests/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Tests/Server/Hubs/HubFacts.cs

    // Arrange

    // Set up the individual mock clients
    var group1 = new Mock<IClientContract>();
    var group2 = new Mock<IClientContract>();
    var group3 = new Mock<IClientContract>();

    group1.Setup(m => m.RaiseAlert(It.IsAny<string>())).Verifiable();
    group2.Setup(m => m.RaiseAlert(It.IsAny<string>())).Verifiable();
    group3.Setup(m => m.RaiseAlert(It.IsAny<string>())).Verifiable();

    // set the Connection Context to return the mock clients
    var mockClients = new Mock<IHubCallerConnectionContext<dynamic>>();
    mockClients.Setup(m => m.Group("1")).Returns(group1.Object);
    mockClients.Setup(m => m.Group("2")).Returns(group2.Object);
    mockClients.Setup(m => m.Group("3")).Returns(group3.Object);

    // Assign our mock context to our hub
    var hub = new NotificationsHub
    {
        Clients = mockClients.Object
    };

    // Act
    hub.RaiseNotificationAlert("2");

    // Assert
    group1.Verify(m => m.RaiseAlert(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Never);
    group2.Verify(m => m.RaiseAlert(""), Times.Once);
    group3.Verify(m => m.RaiseAlert(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Never);
}
```

The code above is checking that my `NotificationsHub.RaiseAlert(string groupId)` method is only triggered on the client side for the specific `groupId` I pass in.

This is the hub that's being tested:

```
public class NotificationsHub : Hub
{
    public void RaiseAlert(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.RaiseAlert(message);
    }

    public void RaiseNotificationAlert(string groupId)
    {
        if (groupId== null)
        {
            // Notify all clients
            Clients.All.RaiseAlert("");
            return;
        }

        // Notify only the client for this userId
        Clients.Group(groupId).RaiseAlert("");

    }
}
```