# Ways to mock SignalR Clients.Group in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, signalr, moq

I'm writing mock test cases for SignalR application. I just started with the help of [Unit Testing SignalR Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-signalr-applications), but my requirement is little bit different that example shown there.
Following is the code I have done after googling.

## SignalRHub

```
public class HubServer : Hub
{
    [HubMethodName("SendNofication")]
    public void GetNofication(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            Clients.Group("Manager").BroadCast(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }        
}
```

## Unit Test

```
public interface IClientContract { }

[TestMethod]
public void GetNoficationTest()
{
    var hub = new HubServer();
    var mockClients = new Mock<IHubCallerConnectionContext<dynamic>>();
    hub.Clients = mockClients.Object;
    var all = new Mock<IClientContract>();
    string message = "Message to send";

    mockClients.Setup(m => m.Group("Manager")).Returns(message);
    mockClients.Setup(m => m.All).Returns(all.Object);

    hub.GetNofication("Mock call to SingalR hub");
    all.VerifyAll();
}
```

I'm beginner in Unit Test application, just want to confirm if this is right way to mock SignalR Groups.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or is this meant to be a code review?

Comment: @Nkosi No error, test passing successfully. It's just for code review to check if it's right way to mock? if not then need your help to correct it.

Comment: I tested the code you had above and it did not pass. My answer blow was based on the fact that your code was not working.

Comment: Test passing successfully with above code in my application. As I told you I'm beginner in writing mock test cases, I just want to confirm if I'm doing that right way.

Comment: I've posted another example of unit testing groups here too in case that's of any help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46953636/1879019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using examples from [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Tests](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/release/tests/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Tests/Server/Hubs/HubFacts.cs)

Hubs Group Are Mockable

The client contract needs to be updated with the necessary methods. In this case you will have to add `Broadcast` method to match how it is called in the Hub

```
public interface IClientContract {
    void Broadcast(string message);
}
```

Next arrange the test by setting up the dependencies for the hub and exercise the method under test.

```
[TestMethod]
public void _GetNoficationTest() {
    // Arrange.
    var hub = new HubServer();
    var mockClients = new Mock<IHubCallerConnectionContext<dynamic>>();
    var groups = new Mock<IClientContract>();
    var message = "Message to send";
    var groupName = "Manager";

    hub.Clients = mockClients.Object;
    groups.Setup(_ => _.Broadcast(message)).Verifiable();
    mockClients.Setup(_ => _.Group(groupName)).Returns(groups.Object);

    // Act.
    hub.GetNofication(message);

    // Assert.
    groups.VerifyAll();
}
```

Another option would be to fake the group using an `ExpandoObject` given that `Clients.Group` in this instance returns `dynamic`

```
[TestMethod]
public void _GetNoficationTest_Expando() {
    // Act.
    var hub = new HubServer();
    var mockClients = new Mock<IHubCallerConnectionContext<dynamic>>();
    dynamic groups = new ExpandoObject();
    var expected = "Message to send";
    string actual = null;
    var groupName = "Manager";
    bool messageSent = false;

    hub.Clients = mockClients.Object;
    groups.Broadcast = new Action<string>(m => {
        actual = m;
        messageSent = true;
    });
    mockClients.Setup(_ => _.Group(groupName)).Returns((ExpandoObject)groups);

    // Act.
    hub.GetNofication(expected);

    // Assert.
    Assert.IsTrue(messageSent);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```