# How to test SignalR 2 hub only notifies a single user?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, signalr, signalr-hub

I've worked through the [unit testing examples in the SignalR 2 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-signalr-applications), but now I'd like to test that my hub only notifies a single user in certain situations.

My hub code looks like this:

```
public class NotificationsHub : Hub
{
    public void RaiseAlert(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.RaiseAlert(message);
    }

    public void RaiseNotificationAlert(string userId)
    {
        if (userId == null)
        {
            // Notify all clients
            Clients.All.RaiseAlert("");
            return;
        }

        // Notify only the client for this userId
        Clients.User(userId).RaiseAlert("");

    }
}
```

My unit test for checking that all clients are notified looks like this (it's based on the Microsoft example):

```
[Test]
public void NotifiesAllUsersWhenNoUserIdSpecified()
{
    // Based on: https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-signalr-applications

    // Arrange

    // This is faking the 
    var mockClients = new Mock<IClientContract>();
    mockClients.Setup(m => m.RaiseAlert(It.IsAny<string>())).Verifiable();

    // A mock of our SignalR hub's clients 
    var mockClientConnCtx = new Mock<IHubCallerConnectionContext<dynamic>>();
    mockClientConnCtx.Setup(m => m.All).Returns(mockClients.Object);

    // Set the hub's connection context to the mock context
    var hub = new NotificationsHub
    {
        Clients = mockClientConnCtx.Object
    };

    // Action
    hub.RaiseNotificationAlert(null);

    // Assert
    mockClients.Verify(m => m.RaiseAlert(It.IsAny<string>()));
}
```

What I'm not sure about is how to change the collection of clients represented by the `var mockClients = new Mock<IClientContract>()` line into a group of individual clients so that I can then test that if I notify user 1, then users 2 and 3 weren't notified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another question about how to unit test groups and [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28867272/1879019) pointed to the [unit tests for the SignalR codebase](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/dev/tests/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Tests/Server/Hubs/HubFacts.cs).

Looking at those examples I worked out that I needed to add mocking of calls to the `User` method of the `mockClients`.  That ended up looking like this:

```
public interface IClientContract
{
    void RaiseAlert(string message);
}

[Test]
public void NotifiesOnlySpecifiedUserWhenUserIdSent()
{
    // Adapted from code here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/dev/tests/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Tests/Server/Hubs/HubFacts.cs

    // Arrange

    // Set up the individual mock clients
    var client1 = new Mock<IClientContract>();
    var client2 = new Mock<IClientContract>();
    var client3 = new Mock<IClientContract>();

    client1.Setup(m => m.RaiseAlert(It.IsAny<string>())).Verifiable();
    client2.Setup(m => m.RaiseAlert(It.IsAny<string>())).Verifiable();
    client3.Setup(m => m.RaiseAlert(It.IsAny<string>())).Verifiable();

    // set the Connection Context to return the mock clients
    var mockClients = new Mock<IHubCallerConnectionContext<dynamic>>();
    mockClients.Setup(m => m.User("1")).Returns(client1.Object);
    mockClients.Setup(m => m.User("2")).Returns(client2.Object);
    mockClients.Setup(m => m.User("3")).Returns(client3.Object);

    // Assign our mock context to our hub
    var hub = new NotificationsHub
    {
        Clients = mockClients.Object
    };

    // Act
    hub.RaiseNotificationAlert("2");

    // Assert
    client1.Verify(m => m.RaiseAlert(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Never);
    client2.Verify(m=>m.RaiseAlert(""), Times.Once);
    client3.Verify(m => m.RaiseAlert(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Never);
}
```